# Set address and name in from using mailable

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a mailable class for sending email in alravel 5.7 and i have some problem getting the name.

In config/mail.php there is a config:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

but i overwritten in .env

```
MAIL_FROM_NAME=test@test.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME='test user'
```

When sending emails with mailable, in the build method i have:

```
return $this->from($this->from)
                    ->subject($this->emailSubject)
                    ->view('email_template')
                    ->with('data', $this->data);
```

The email is sent and it shows from who: (test@test.com) but the name is not available.

Why??

*** UPDATE ***

I forgot to clear the cache :)

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

Now it works. It is not necessary the from() method if you have overwritten in .env

```
MAIL_FROM_NAME=
MAIL_FROM_NAME=
```

Comment: if you are using the name and email globally then just simply use `'from' => ['address' => 'example@example.com', 'name' => 'App Name'],` in your `config/app.php` and it won't require to use `$this->from()` in your `build method`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the [second argument](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php#L454) to `Mailable::from()` which gives the name.

> However, if your application uses the same "from" address for all of its emails, it can become cumbersome to call the `from` method in each mailable class you generate. Instead, you may specify a global "from" address in your `config/mail.php` configuration file. This address will be used if no other "from" address is specified within the mailable class:
>
> `'from' => ['address' => 'example@example.com', 'name' => 'App Name'],`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#generating-mailables

In other words, if you don't need a per-environment return address, just set the value directly in `config/mail.php`.

Comment: even if i set explicit:

`return $this->from('test@test.com', 'test app name')`
does not work. It shows the email from MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS (from env) but not the name

Answer (score 3):

remove the from method if is different then what's in env or use

```
return $this->from(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'))
                ->subject($this->emailSubject)
                ->view('email_template')
                ->with('data', $this->data);
```

Comment: i have tried removing the from method and use config....but the same problem. It only show the email but not the name

Comment: the problem was the cache. This cache kills me :))